# Which global gitignore am I using?

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

I am new to git.  Some time ago, I have set it up on my MacBook Pro and havent used it for months.  Now I wonder how can I figure out following:

1. Did I set already global gitignore and how to find out where it is located on my MacBookPro?
2. Did I set multiple global gitignore files and how to find where they are on my system?
3. If I have multiple global gitignore files, which one I is set to be used by git currently?

Please, provide best explanation, I am new to both MacBook terminal and git.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gitignore you are using is the one in the closest parent directory to where your git repo is initialized. So if you have a file system like this:

```
root/
  | .gitignore
  | user/
     | .gitignore
     | dev/
         | .gitignore
         | project/
```

If `project` is the directory of your git repository then the .gitignore being used is the one in `dev` as it is the closest parent to `project`.

To check what your global .gitignore is run `git config --get core.excludesfile`.

Comment: Thanks but what I see is that I have files .gitignore and .gitignore-global in my root.  So, I am trying to figure out which one of these 2 is being set as my global gitignore file so I can delete the other one.

Comment: You can check which of the two is your global gitignore using `git config --get core.excludesfile`.